# What is the proper way to apply a css rule to an element under another one?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

`h3 p {background-color:red}`  I thought would affect anything in a p tag that's under an h3 tag.  It doesn't.

I thought I could do this with:

```
element element {rule;}
```

[image]

I saw [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_element.asp) thinking that maybe you could only do it with elements under divs.. but it didn't work for any p under div either.

[image]

Comment: See [Adjacent Sibling Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

Comment: element1 element2 = element2 inside element1, element1 + element2 = element1 at the same level as element2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS rule `h3 p {background-color:red}` is implying that you want to make the background of `<p>` tag *within* an `<h3>` tag red. So that would be:

```
<h3>h3 tag
    <p>paragraph</p>
</h3>
```

This is called nesting. But you cannot nest a paragraph within a heading, this is invalid. However you could nest the paragraph inside a div like this:

```
<div>This is a div
    <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
```

And your CSS `div p {background-color:red}` would work.

Comment: I see what I did wrong and your explanation is great,

Answer (score 3):

Space separated selectors means child selector. You are looking for [sibling selectors](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/).

### [Adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```css
h3 + p {background-color:red}
```

```html
<h3>header</h3>
<p>paragraph</p>
<p>paragraph</p>
```

### [General sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors):

```css
h3 ~ p {background-color:red}
```

```html
<h3>header</h3>
<p>paragraph</p>
<p>paragraph</p>
```

Comment: Alexander, how did you get the buttons with "Run code snippet", etc in your answer?

Comment: @spex5 It's next to the insert image button and two over from the `{}` code formatting button. See [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) for information.

Answer (score 1):

To do this your p element must be in a div tag.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    div p {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
<body>

    <div>i am div

    <p>hello in red color</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The p element is only "under" the h3 element physically, not hierarchically. Try:

```
h3+p {
    background-color:red;
}
```

[for further info see sibling selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)